# FROM: header is forged, SENDER: is legit , spam is delivered. how to detect?

Tags: spam, exim, spf

**In short:**

What happens: **FROM:** header is forged, **SENDER:** is legit , spam is delivered.
What I need: Detect forged **FROM:** header when possible, block delivery

**Explained:**

I have a exim server that receives/sends mails for my clients. I activated both SPF & DKIM for my client but from what I researched SPF checks only the envelope **SENDER**.

How can I make exim execute the same SPF validation steps on the **FROM:** header?
Or do you have other ideeas on how to solve this problem.?

Example of message that ended in inbox:

```
Return-path: <stupendouslylq@ritenour.k12.mo.us>
Envelope-to: office@myclient.ro
Delivery-date: Wed, 16 May 2012 22:51:37 +0300
Received: from 173.137.18.95.dynamic.jazztel.es ([95.18.137.173]:3344)
        by genius.filipnet.ro with esmtp (Exim 4.77)
        (envelope-from <stupendouslylq@ritenour.k12.mo.us>)
        id 1SUkG0-0006yl-SG
        for office@myclient.ro; Wed, 16 May 2012 22:51:37 +0300
Received: from apache by ncjobbbneebppofandpfe.nobleenergyinc.com with local (Exim 4.67)
        (envelope-from <<office@myclient.ro>>)
        id VF1VAG-QZSQV9-C6
        for <office@myclient.ro>; Wed, 16 May 2012 20:51:36 +0100
To: <office@myclient.ro>
Subject: We invite you to work in your spare time for $ 100 per hour
X-PHP-Script: ncjobbbneebppofandpfe.greaterlouisville.com/sendmail.php for 95.18.137.173
From: <office@myclient.ro>
X-Sender: <office@myclient.ro>
X-Mailer: PHP
X-Priority: 1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-2"
Message-Id: <Y87CJM-XJEZZ1-VU@ncjobbbneebppofandpfe.lsinter.net>
```

Comment: edited title to be more relevant

Comment: If your problem is that people can lie about who wrote something, the answer is that no solution is known. At least you can validate who sent it from you. If the problem is that you can't reliably detect 100% of spam -- again, no solution is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undesirable for a number of reasons; here's one.  I have SPF records set up for my domain.  If I send email to a legitimate mailing list to which you subscribe, the mailing list server will send that out to all list recipients with my `From:` line still in place.  If you test the `From:` header, with my domain in it, against my SPF records, you'll get a FAIL, because I don't list the mail servers for every list I subscribe to in my SPF records, and nor should I.  So you'll reject the email; that would be bad, so you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: U are right, haven't thought of that.

Comment: Maybe you have other ideeas for my problem to be solved ?

Comment: i can't vote up your answer :( don't have the rep

Comment: But you can accept it, by clicking the "tick" outline next to it; this is something you should do for any question you ask, when you're happy with an answer.  It drives the SF reputation system.